# Calling an API from one localhost to another

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, json

I am new to Angular and I am trying to create an application that uses the API of another application that I've created. The application with the API is an ASP.NET MVC application written mostly in C# that sends JSON data.

```
var app = angular.module("adminSite", []);

app.controller("InventoryController", function ($scope, $http) {


    $http.jsonp("http://localhost:57747/api/APIUsers/10?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.user = response.data;
    });


    $scope.message = "ANGULAR TESTING";
}
);
```

Above is the controller for my Angular page that is simply trying to pull the data from the API.

Im getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " Error because the JSONP is messing up with the regular JSON code but I don't know what to do to fix it and I've been searching for quite some time.

Comment: Please post your controller code.  Are you using both WebApi Controller (to get the data) and MVC Controller (MVC Controller to display view)?

Comment: As I remember JSONP expects JSON where every key wrapped with double quotes. Most of chances this is the case.